# Using an explicit content type causes WebAPI serialization to fail

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, json, asp.net-web-api

When issuing a PUT or POST command to a WebApi, using explicit content types causes WebAPI serialization to fail. For example, the following ajax call will fail:

```
$("#updateStudent").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                var json = {
                    "firstName": $("#firstName").val(),
                    "middleInitial": $("#middleInitial").val(),
                    "lastName": $("#lastName").val(),
                    "birthDate": $("#birthDate").val(),
                    "gender": $("#gender").val()
                };

                $.ajax({
                    url: "api/students/1",
                    type: "PUT",
                    accept: "application/json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: json
                }
                ).done(function (data) {
                    bindStudentDetail(data);
                });
            });
```

I can fix the issue by removing the contentType from the ajax options parameter, but I'd be very interested to know why this is happening. I've done a little digging and it looks like the json I'm encoding is being converted back into a form encoded format like this:

`firstName=Carlos&middleInitial=R&lastName=Alexander&birthDate=10%2F7%2F1985&gender=Male`

Has anyone ran into this and is there any way that I can choose to be explicit about these requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to actually send a json string (your `json` variable is a javascript object, not a json string):

```
$.ajax({
    //...
    data: JSON.stringify(json)
})
```